# Express the statements using quantifiers example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers, predicate-logic

I'm having a little trouble understanding quantifiers and therefore doubting all my homework answers. Since there is no where to check if the answers are correct, I'm very very worried I am just practicing incorrectly. So I've set up two examples with what I think the answers are.

It would be brilliant if you could confirm if I am correct or not so I could use these answers as a base to check my other answers. If I am incorrect, it would be awesome if you could point me the right direction!

Express the statements using quantifiers. 
*note: ~ = negation.

a) Everybody knows everybody.

my answer: ∀xE(x), E(x) = knows everybody.

b) Somebody knows everybody.

my answer: ∃xE(x)

c) There is somebody whom no one knows.

my answer: ~∃xE(x)

Comment: I think you need to start over, with a binary predicate $K(x,y)$ meaning $x$ knows $y$.

Comment: Also, (c) means "there is no man who knows everybody", which is definitely not the same as "there is somebody whom no one knows"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using $E(x)$ to mean "$x$ knows everybody", it might be more helpful to use something like $K(x,y)$ to mean "$x$ knows $y$".

Using this, these could be stated as:

a) $\forall x\, \forall y\, K(x,y)$

b) $\exists x\, \forall y\, K(x,y)$

c) $\exists x\, \forall y\, \neg K(y,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably more in the intent of the exercises to let $R(x, y)$ be "$x$ knows $y$," and to use double-quantifiers... Also, you should technically have a domain (e.g. all people)

But, your answers for `a` and `b` are correct (`c` is wrong, see comments), given your definition of $E$ and assuming you aren't required to list the domain.

For an example of double quantifiers:
Let $R(x, y)$ be "$x$ knows $y$," and let $D$ be the set of all people.  Then:
$$\text{"Everybody knows somebody"} \iff \forall x \in D,\exists y\in D \text{ such that } R(x, y)$$

Comment: That statement is ambiguous though. It may mean that everybody loves the same person, or that everybody loves at least one person that doesn't have to be the same. You formalised the second meaning.

Comment: @Lyanna While I can see your point, the  issue with exercises like these (converting English to quantifiers) is that there is nearly always ambiguity. This means we must use the most reasonable English-language intent, which (in this case) is that the "somebody" is not necessarily the same person. If the other meaning were intended for this exercise, it would be more clear to write "there is a person everyone knows."